# Get image array from display in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I have a pong game that is a simple pygame environment. I would like to get the numpy array of the image at each instance from the `pygame.display`. I am unable to find the method which gives the numpy array of the entire display. Thanks.

[image: pong]

Comment: You're looking for [surfarray](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html)s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pygame.surfarray.pixels2d`, `pygame.surfarray.array2d`, `pygame.surfarray.pixels3d`, or `pygame.surfarray.array3d` to create a pixel array from a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object (see [`pygame.surfarray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html) module):

```py
import pygame

# [...]

window = pygame.display.set_mode()
```

```py
array2D = pygame.surfarray.array2d(window)
```

```py
array3D = pygame.surfarray.array3d(window)
```

While `array*` creates copies of the pixels from a *Surface* object, `pixel*` creates a new array that directly references the pixel values ​​in a *Surface* object.
The `*2d` version generates a two-dimensional array, with each pixel represented by a single integral value. The `*3d` version generates a three-dimensional array in which each color channel is represented by an integer value.